# Include module into method ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, module, include

I have used module to extend class functionality. But suddenly I wonder if it is ok if I include a module directly into a method of the class instead of into the class like this:

Original use:

model:

```
class Baby
  include CommunicationSkills

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

module:

```
module CommunicationSkills
  def greet
    "Hi"
  end
end
```

so we can:

```
ivan = Baby.new('Iván')
ivan.greet
=> "Hi"
```

but what if I include the method inside a method directly:

```
class Baby

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(language)
    extend GreetLanguages
    send(language)
  end
end
```

module:

```
module GreetLanguages
  def spanish
    "Hola"
  end

  def english
     "Hi"
  end
end
```

so:

```
ivan = Baby.new('Iván')
ivan.greet('spanish')
=> "Hola"
ivan.greet('english')
=> "Hi"
```

I know that this is posible, but conceptually it is right?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: I get an error at the include line: `> ivan.greet('spanish')
NoMethodError: undefined method `include' for #<Baby:0x007ff75228cf98 @name="Ivan">`

Comment: yeah, regarding @davidhu2000 I updated the code. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module contains two instance methods. You want to send them to an instance, not to the class, so you need to `include` the module (using [Module#include](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-include)), not `extend`it.  To invoke `include` from within an instance method (`self` being the instance), you must send `include` to `self.class`. You therefore need to write the following.

```
class Baby
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
  def greet(language)
    self.class.include GreetLanguages
    send(language)
  end
end

ivan = Baby.new('Iván')
ivan.greet('spanish')
  #=> "Hola"

Baby.instance_methods.include?(:english) && Baby.instance_methods.include?(:spanish)
  #=> true

ivan.greet('english')
  #=> "Hi"
```

You can alternatively write `ivan.greet(:spanish)`.

You would use [Object#extend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-extend) if you wanted to convert the instance methods in the module to class methods when you bring them into the class.

```
class Baby
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
  def extend_mod
    self.class.extend GreetLanguages
  end
end

Baby.new('Iván').extend_mod
Baby.methods.include?(:spanish) && Baby.methods.include?(:english) #=> true  

Baby.spanish
  #=> "Hola"
Baby.english
  #=> "Hi"
```

It is unusual to invoke `include` or `extend` from within an instance method. I don't know why one would want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
module GreetLanguages
  def spanish
    "Hola"
  end

  def english
    "Hi"
  end
end

class Baby

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(language)
    extend GreetLanguages
    send(language)
  end
end
```

So, I managed to get this code working using `extend`. Also, in your `send` function, you need to remove the quotes, because you are not sending the string `"language"`, you are sending the variable language which represent the string `"spanish"` or `"english"`.

So, `include` doesn't have a direct receiver, so it is basically calling it on `self`. When you use `include` in the instance method for the class `Baby`, you are adding the module to an instance of `ivan`, which doesn't make any sense.

`extend` adds the module as class methods, so the instance itself can call the method. So, we are adding the module to the instance of `ivan`, and now when we can call `greet`.

I really can't see any reason for doing this, it's best to use `include` in the class level.

Comment: `greet` method is throwing an error on an instance of `Baby`.

Comment: I'm calling `greet(spanish)` and the error I get is: `undefined local variable or method `spanish' for main:Object (NameError)`.

Comment: you need to put spanish in quotes, like `greet('spanish')`, because you are passing in a string, not a variable

Comment: But, what if calling the module takes a lot of time, so I want to use it after a validation inside the method, not for every instance of the class. I mean, I want to use this method or not after validating something inside the instance method? @davidhu2000

Comment: Is `GreetLanguages` added to the singleton class of each instance?

Comment: the reason to add module into method is in order to load some data from mongo by the module only when the class method is called.